# Debugging Android apps from JDB(within Emacs)

Tags: android, emacs, jdb

Ok, so I've been trying to debug Android apps from jdb.

I run the emulator, install the app, run ddms and then I launch the app and then select it in DDMS. Now I run jdb with the following command

> jdb -attach localhost:8700 -sourcepath /project-root/src

jdb is able to attach to the process, and then a command such as

> > stop in com.android.helloworld.onClick

works well.

However, when I use C-x space in Emacs, it runs a command with the line number,

> > stop at com.android.helloworld:22

and I get this output

> Unable to set breakpoint com.android.helloworld:22 : No code at line 22 in 
>   com.android.helloworld

I have checked that the line number is correct, and tried to pass the filename itself, to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem. Typing the number of line is far easier than method.

Answer (score 2):

The Android SDK comes with an `android.el` that has the '`android-jdb`' command in it.  That will set up the keybindings correctly for you.  (At least, I presume it will, I didn't try those keybindings last time I was using it.)

As a bonus, if you try out CEDET from the bzr trunk, it includes android support.  After basic CEDET setup (see cedet.info for android details) it has a convenience for quickly starting up the debugger and attaching to your device with the debugger.  It supports some other fun stuff too.